# combine validation functions in jquery and replace class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm validating my form for required fields, and wish to replace the class "standard_input" with the class "standard_input_error" but my following code won't work. Also, is it possible to combine functions so that I don't need to write a function for each id that requires validation (there are some text fields that don't require validation, so I can't use it for the entire form). Thanks in advance.

```
$('#firstname').blur(function()
{
    if( !$(this).val() ) {
          $(this).addClass('standard_input_error');
    }
});


Firstname * <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="standard_input"> 
Last Name*  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="standard_input">
another   * <input type="text" id="another" name="another" class="standard_input"> 
another 2   <input type="text" id="another2" name="another2" class="standard_input">
Field      * <input type="text" id="fieldb" name="fieldb" class="standard_input"> 
Blah blah   <input type="text" id="blah" name="blah" class="standard_input">

Checkbox 1* <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="cbox1" name="cbox1" />
Blah bla 1 <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="blabla" name="blabla" />
Blee blee1* <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="blee" name="blee" />
bloblo 1   <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="blo" name="blo" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.validate').bind('blur',function(){
    if (!$(this).val()){
        $(this).removeClass('standard_input');
        $(this).addClass('standard_input_error');
        return false;
    }
});
```

where 'validate' is the class applied to input fields which need validation

Answer (score 0):

For the textboxes use this:

```
$('form').find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).removeClass('standard_input').addClass('standard_input_error');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a generic function and reuse that:

```
$('form input[type="text"]').blur(myValidation);

function myValidation() {
  if( !$.trim( this.value) ) {
      $(this).removeClass('standard_input').addClass('standard_input_error');
  } else {
      $(this).removeClass('standard_input_error');
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uvepey/6/edit)**